Is it possible to get the Fabric Capacity Operations metrics via an API?
I wish to monitor all the operations in my fabric capacity (or workspace scope).
I've checked out the Fabric REST API, but it seems to be focused on CRUD only, not monitoring.
The generic Azure REST API has a Fabric - Operations - List option, but the documentation is really lackluster and I'm not quite sure what it is returning. A list of available RBAC permissions or something?
So, does there exist an API for retrieving Microsoft Fabric Capacity Operation Information/Status?
The data I'm after is basically the same as what is displayed in the Fabric Capacity Metrics App, under "background operation by timespan", although additional info, especially error details would be very welcome.


Check if this helps https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Fabric-Capacity-metrics-data-REST-API-or-alternate-ways-to-pull/m-p/3789709

This is planned under this roadmap item:

Fabric monitoring Estimated release timeline: Q4 2024
Release Type: Public preview
Fabric workspace administrators and developers require access to
detailed diagnostic logs and workload metrics to troubleshoot
performance issues, capacity performance, and data downtime. As part
of the Fabric Monitoring feature we intend to provide a read-only
database of workspace logs that users can query ad-hoc, analyze for
patterns and anomalies, or save drafted queries to as query sets. This
helps drive investigations on root-cause analysis for errors, long
running queries, refresh failures, and other issues. We will continue
to enhance this feature by adding in-context monitoring and
diagnostics experiences.

Fabric Roadmap: Fabric monitoring

Thank you for the answer. ill leave the question open until its possible then
